# Troubleshooting Issues with My PHP Contact Form – Form submission does not arrive to my email inbox

Tags: php

Once the form is filled out and submitted it does not arrive to my email inbox.

This is a php contact form, where the user can enter
Name, Email, Business Name, Business Website, Message, and Verify that they are human by clicking on a checkbox.

The PHP code checks that the fields aren't empty, and display error messages in case they user does not fill the form correctly.

I have tried looking for a solution for 2 weeks... I would appreciate hearing any feedback as to why it is not working.

Note:
The reason why I have not defined the "action" attribute in the form element is because it happens within the same file.

This is the PHP code above the html tag

```
<?php
if($_POST['submit']) {

  // user_name
  if(!$_POST['user_name']){
    $error="<br/>- Please enter your name";
  }
  
  // user_email
  if(!$_POST['user_email']){
    $error.="<br/>- Please enter your email";
  }

  // business_name
  if(!$_POST['business_name']){
    $error.="<br/>- Please enter your business name";
  }
  
  // business_website
  if(!$_POST['business_website']){
    $error.="<br/>- Please enter your business website";
  }
  
  // user_message
  if(!$_POST['user_message']){
    $error.="<br/>- Please enter your message";
  }
  
  // user_verify
  if(!$_POST['user_verify']){
    $error="<br/>- Please confirm you are human";
  }

  // ERRORS
  if($error){
    $result="Whoops, there is an error. Please correct the following: $error";
  } else {
    mail("EMAIL@EXAMPLE.COM", "FORM MESSAGE",
    "Name:" .$_POST['user_name'].
    "\r\n Email:" .$_POST['user_email'].
    "\r\n Business Name:" .$_POST['business_name'].
    "\r\n Business Website:" .$_POST['business_website'].
    "\r\n Message:" .$_POST['user_message']);

    {
      $result="Thank you, We'll be in touch shortly";
    }
  }
}

?>
```

Html Code.  "there is some php in  the value attribute of the  elements

```
      <?php echo $result;?>
      <form class="form" method="post" role="form">

        FORM USERNAME
        <!-- form group -->
        <div class="form-group form-group-half">
          <input 
            type="text"
            name="user_name"
            id="user_name" required
            autocomplete="off"
            value="<?php echo $_POST['user_name']; ?>"
            />

          <label for="user_name" class="form-label"> Name </label>
        </div>

        FORM EMAIL
        <!-- form group -->
        <div class="form-group form-group-half">
          <input
            type="email"
            name="user_email"
            id="user_email"
            placeholder=" "
            autocomplete="off"
            value="<?php echo $_POST['user_email']; ?>"
            required/>

          <label for="user_email" class="form-label"> Email </label>
        </div>

        FORM BUSINESS NAME
        <!-- form group -->
        <div class="form-group form-group-half">
          <input 
            type="text"
            name="business_name" id="business_name"
            autocomplete="off"
            value="<?php echo $_POST['business_name']; ?>"
            required/>

          <label for="business_name" class="form-label"> Business Name </label>
        </div>

         
        FORM BUSINESS WEBSITE NAME
        <!-- form group -->
        <div class="form-group form-group-half">
          <input
            type="text"
            name="business_website"
            id="business_website"
            autocomplete="off"
            value="<?php echo $_POST['business_website']; ?>"
            required/>

          <label for="business_website" class="form-label"> Website </label>
        </div>


        FORM MESSAGE
        <!-- form group -->
        <div class="form-group form-group-second-last">
          <textarea
            name="user_message"
            id="user_message"
            class="form_message"
            placeholder=" "
            autocomplete="off"
            required
          ><?php echo $_POST['user_message'];?></textarea>

          <label for="user_message" class="form-label"> Message </label>
        </div>
        
        CHECKBOX to verify
        <!-- form group -->
        <div class="form-group form-group-last">
          <label for="user_verify" class="custom">
            I'm not a robot
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              name="user_verify"
              id="user_verify">
             
          <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
        </div>

        SUBMIT BUTTON
        <!-- form group -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <input
            type="submit"
            name="submit"
            value="Let's Get Creative"
            class="link-secondary"
          />
        </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: What does the call to `mail()` return? What is your hosting environment?

Comment: The mail() Designates the email recipient, and populates the email message with the information that the user input into the form fields.

I've been testing the functionality of this by putting it up website server. I use FileZilla to upload the files, and to test it live on the actual domain.

Comment: `mail()` returns a true or false value. What is it returning? Do something like `$ret = mail(...); var_dump($ret);` What OS is the server? Linux? Windows? Is it a container? A shared hosting account on GoDaddy?

Comment: @AlexHowansky I am a beginner at this, however I am hosting my website with GoDaddy. 

I upload the index.php file to the server and once the changes are reflected onto the page, I try to submit my form, without any success yet.

  Sorry that my limited knowledge is leaving gaps. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: GoDaddy is notoriously strict with outbound email. You're probably best off calling their support to make sure you have your environment configured correctly to use their servers.

Comment: @AlexHowansky That is a great suggestion. I will certainly contact the Godaddy support to ensure that there aren't any overlooked details that may be preventing the form being submitted.